# pgAdmin III installed after postgres - how do I view/connect to existing databases?

Tags: macos, postgresql, pgadmin

I'm so new to this I'm not even sure I know how to ask the question, but hopefully it makes sense:

I installed postgres on OS X Yosemite (following these instructions: https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.10-yosemite) and have made some databases.

Having used Microsoft SQL Server in the past, I wanted a GUI with which to view the databases so I downloaded and installed pgAdmin III (using the first link on http://www.postgresql.org/download/macosx/).  Unfortunately, it seems like pgAdmin III has just installed a new instance of postgres, as it doesn't show any of the databases I made (within Terminal) in the original postgres installation.

Does anyone know how to amend my settings in pgAdmin III so that it just acts as a 'screen' for the existing postgres installation?

Comment: Downloaded from where? Link? Some PostgreSQL distributions bundle PgAdmin-III but it's also available standalone. How *exactly* did you install it? It sounds like even if it did install another PostgreSQL instance all you need to do is connect to your other one and save the password.

Comment: Hi Craig, I think I did just download pgAdmin III from the first link on  http://www.postgresql.org/download/macosx/, so it looks like I probably did install a new instance. The first postgres was installed separately and earlier using the link I posted.  The solution probably is as simple as you say, I just don't know how to connect to the old instance. Appreciate it probably sounds ridiculously easy, but it takes me an eternity to understand any documentation on postgres and I don't even know which one would answer this question.

Comment: PostgreSQL doesn't care that you have multiple installs, although you'll want to clean that up eventually. I think you want to start with File | Add Server, which will lead you to a [dialog](http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/1.20/connect.html) that you'll probably have more questions about.

Comment: Thanks Mike, I have worked out what to do.  Based on how little information I had to supply to connect to the right database, am I right to assume that a port and a name is enough to define a specific database (i.e., presumably two databases of the same name cannot be listening on the same port?)?  The other part I was stuck on was the username which was initially down as 'postgres', but after googling my error (psql: FATAL: role “postgres” does not exist) I found a post which suggested running psql from terminal and entering "\du" and then pressing enter.  This gave me the required username.